# Passing object attribute in each statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I am attempting to use an object's parameter in a `link_to` as follows:

```
<% @step.images.each do |pic| %>
     <script>
        alert(<%=pic.id%>);
     </script>

     <li class = "span2" id="picture_<%=pic.id %>">
         <div class="thumbnail">
             <%=image_tag(pic.url.to_s, :width => "100%") %>
                  <p style="text-align: center;">
              <!-- ERROR ON LINE BELOW FOR LINK_TO PATH -->
              <%= link_to edit_step_image_path("<%=pic.id%>"), :class=> "btn btn-mini" do %>
                   <i class="icon-edit"></i>
              <% end %>

              <a href="#" class="btn btn-mini btn-delete" confirm="Are you sure you want to delete this photo?" data-method="delete">
                <i class="icon-trash"></i>
             </a>
        </div>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

I checked that my alert does pass the right id, but when I attempt to use the `pic.id` in my `link_to`, I get a syntax error.  Removing the parenthetical around `<%=pic.id%>` gets rid of the error but gives me the wrong id.

How might I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re trying to interpolate ERB inside ERB, which just won’t work. You’re already in Ruby code, so just write Ruby! Instead use this:

```
<%= link_to edit_step_image_path(pic.id), :class=> "btn btn-mini" do %>
```

Comment: When I do that, it doesn't give me the right pic.id.  It should be "2", but it gives me 0 (which is different than what I get from the alert).

Comment: whoops, I just realized I forgot to pass two parameters for the nested resource.  after I changed it to 
<%= link_to edit_step_image_path(@step, pic.id), :class=> "btn btn-mini" do %>
it worked.  Thanks!